# Cookie value c#

Tags: c#, cookies

My question is if this is the correct way to get the value of a cookie in c#. My intentions are only to get the value of a specific cookie and store in a string variable which i named "cookie" in the example.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
(request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
String cookie = response.Cookies[cookiename].ToString();
```

Comment: waiting to get into production so i can try it, but i have also seen in examples that instead of response.Cookies[cookiename] people use request.Cookies[cookiename], what is the difference between this two?

Comment: One is the cookie on the response, the other is on the request. It is the difference of sending cookies and receiving cookies, respectively.

Comment: so if i meant in the example on receving a cookie it should be request.Cookies[cookiename]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look:

Save Cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookieName"] == null)
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookieName"));

        Response.Cookies["cookieName"].Expires.AddYears(5);
        Response.Cookies["cookieName"]["keyValue"] = "string value";   
        Response.AppendCookie(Response.Cookies["cookieName"]);
```

Recover cookie:

```
HttpCookie CookieKey = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
        if (CookieKey != null)
        {
            string value = CookieKey["keyValue"]; 
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks! i tried that earlier the recover part and it said no Request declare in scope, so i made the Request object. Will this be ok? btw whats the difference between the "keyvalue" and "cookiename" or are they the same? 

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpCookie CookieKey = Request.Cookies["cookieName"];
        if (CookieKey != null)
        {
            string value = CookieKey["keyValue"]; 
        }

Comment: Hi @rdk1992 , a cookie can have multiple values​​. So use this:Response.Cookies["cookieName"]["name"] = "name";Response.Cookies["cookieName"]["age"] = "age";

Comment: i meant in the lower part, the part of recover cookie: i dont mean to create a cookie just to get the value of one. So i guide myself with your example of the recover cookie section. Question is that you have Request.Cookies, tried this and gave me error that request is not declared. so my question is that if the request object should be declared like this:"WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);"

Answer (score 0):

Besides error checking (timeouts, exceptions) - finding cookies by name is supported with

```
string cookie = response.Cookies[cookiename].ToString();
```

So "yes" is the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Cookies` is used for reacting to the request on the server - `Response.Cookies` will create a cookie if it doesnt exist while you are on the server - since this is outside the context of the server executing code, this is appropriate.